# Subdivision not working as intended, edges not generating

Tags: modeling

Blender newbie here, attempting to model some things and experiencing issues with subdivision and with odd things generating where there shouldn't be, not sure how to describe it but hopefully videos will show what I mean.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17yxSbMX708quhmW1K4fpA_6hY90ObYI4/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wOkDcvhu0unBOIQIGEppBo-MZZs7C0cD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello it looks like you've selected the edges of a big ngon face? If you subdivide it will just subdivide the edges, i.e. create new vertices along these edges, not create small faces within the big face. Maybe first remove the big face and use a tool like Grid Fill to create quad faces?

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.
Next I figure out how to mark an answer...

Comment: I can make it an answer but first try the solution and tell if it works?

Comment: Next time you ask a question, try to describe the problem with words. 
Something like: "I've added a vertex to an edge, and now the subdivision modifier doesn't look right"
Moreover if you want to add a split to the face use ctrl+r

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what you select is not a grid of quads but a big ngon, i.e. a face with more than 4 vertices, like this for example:

[image]

If you subdivide this kind of face it will just add vertices to the edges, it won't subdivide the face itself. To create a grid made of quads, first thing select all and <kbd>X</kbd> *(Delete) > Only Faces* then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Result (now you have quads only and it will subdivide correctly if needed):

[image]

That said we need to see the whole topology because it may not be a good idea to subdivide this part only. Also, another way to add topology is to join vertices (<kbd>J</kbd>) or use the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd>).